# AngularJS with Adobe AIR

Tags: angularjs, air

I am creating an PoC app using Adobe AIR with AngularJS, the main idea behind this is that the first version will run as stand-alone and then we will host it somewhere to make it web-based. When I started to test ng-model, ng-click and some other basic notations, it seems that AIR doesn't like them and is unable to angularize the DOM. My guess is that the way that AIR parses and renders the DOM is different from what is expected from AngularJS, although it supposes to use Webkit(and it actually behaves like Safari, CSS3 wise).

Is there a way to force angular to wait to compile? Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  AIR haters gonna hate or what?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I am just encouraging the AIR haters or whoever downvoted my valid question but he/she didn't have an answer or more questions. So, just because I didn't want to re-work creating this on MXML/AS3 and then rewriting on HTML/JS(i won't post an app on AIR mainly because of the skinning), I went with Node-Webkit. So far, so good.

If you need to do something like what I am trying to do, I guess that Node-Webkit is a good alternative. I think that the installer will be more work than just packaging an AIR app but I couldn't make AngularJS to work on AIR.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually bootstrap angular - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Typically, developers allow angular to automatically bootstrap by adding ng-app="myApp" to the DOM node they want to "angularize".  To manually bootstrap, remove that attribute altogether, then run the code below when you want to initialize angular.

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('#myAppContainer'), ['myApp']);
```

That said, my opinion is that your switch from AIR to Node-Webkit was a great choice and is the way to go.